# How do I initialize a constexpr std::array of std::pair<int, const char[]>?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr, stdarray

In C++14, how do I initialize a global constexpr `std::array` of `std::pair` containing text strings? The following doesn't work:

```cpp
#include <array>
    
constexpr std::array<std::pair<int, const char[]>, 3> strings = {
  {0, "Int"},
  {1, "Float"},
  {2, "Bool"}};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are almost there. First of all, the `char const[]` type needs to be a pointer instead, because it is an incomplete type, that may not be held in a `std::pair`. And secondly, you are missing a pair of braces. The correct declaration will look like this:

```
constexpr std::array<std::pair<int, const char*>, 3> strings = {{
  {0, "Int"},
  {1, "Float"},
  {2, "Bool"},
}};
```

The extra braces are required because `std::array` is an aggregate holding a raw C array, and so we need the braces mentioned explicitly so that `{0, "Int"}` is not taken erroneously as the initializer for the inner array object.

Comment: Why the relaxed aggregate initialization in C++14 doesn't work here? `std::array<std::string,2> s = {"Hi","Hello"};` and `std::array<std::string,2> s = {{"Hi, "Hello"}};` are both deemed identical after C++14 (in case of non-constexpr array). Why doesn't the same rule apply here ?

Comment: @aep - The brace elision algorithm has issues knowing that you mean to initialize the first pair and not the inner array.

Comment: I think with a bit of experiment I now understand the difference. Was mucking a bit around with a few combinations like `std::array<std::string, 2> s={"hi", "hello"};`, `std::array<std::string, 2> s={{"hi", "hello"}};`, std::array<std::string, 2> s={{"hi"}, {"hello"}};`, std::array<std::string, 2> s={{{"hi"}, {"hello"}}};` to see the difference. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in C++20 is to use `std::to_array` which allows you to create an array where you don't need to specify the size up front.

```
constexpr auto strings = std::to_array<std::pair<int, const char*>>({
{0, "Int"},
{1, "Float"},
{2, "Bool"},
});
```

Comment: `std::to_array` is of questionable benefit here. If you're making your answer specific to C++20, you should probably also use `std::string_view` instead of `const char*`. Having the size information can be a big performance boost in some cases.